# MySQL 5.5 Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data status variable missing

Tags: mysql-5.5

We're running a MySQL 5.5.29 server in Production. If I do:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

I'm not getting the status variable 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data' which according to [the official documentation for this version](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data) should be there. What am I missing here?

Comment: `mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS where variable_name IN ('Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data');` is working perfectly for me.

Comment: Not for me unfortunately: `ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data' in 'where clause'`. But this is another problem. There is just no such statvar!?

Answer (score 0):

Run `show global status like 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data';`

Comment: Please study carefully the formatting options and https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer to see what makes a good answer.